# SwiftUI: unexpected refresh of view with autogeneratet text

Tags: swiftui

The question is: when user clicks the view, the autogenerated text will refresh the Text View.
I expect only the rectangle stroke change the color when click it.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        ZStack{

            Rectangle()
                .stroke(self.selected ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.3,height: geometry.size.height*0.2)
            Text(self.createText())
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.3,height: geometry.size.height*0.2)

        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            if  self.selected {
                self.selected = false
            }else{
                self.selected = true
            }

            print(self.selected)
        }

    }
}

private func createText() -> String {

    return result = arc4random_uniform(self.userData.maxNumber)
}
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8G42.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What are you expecting to happen? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `@State` changed the `body` got rebuild, so everything within it executed (after all it is just a computable property, ie. closure, ie. function), so all functions & constructors within it.

If you want you generated text is not changed on main view refreshed, you have to move it into separated view and don't use autogeneration in initialisation (because constructor is called on refresh).

Here is how it could be done (tested with Xcode 11.4):

```swift
...
Rectangle()
    .stroke(self.selected ? Color.blue : Color.white)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.3,height: geometry.size.height*0.2)
RandomTextView() // << separated view 
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.3,height: geometry.size.height*0.2)
...
```

And view itself

```swift
struct RandomTextView: View {
    @State private var number = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text(number)
            .onAppear {
                self.number = self.createText()
            }
    }

    private func createText() -> String {
        return "\(arc4random_uniform(1111))" // << demo, pass here needed max
    }
}
```